# Split class definition with full control over subclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, subclassing

I have a rather lengthy class for data analysis. In this class there are functions for input, output, plotting, different analysis steps and so on. I really would like to split this class to smaller, easier to read subclasses.

The most easy way would of course be to define a superclass and then inherit multiple subclasses. However, this is not what I want because functions of on subclass cannot change the variables of another subclass.

What I want to have is a splitting of the class definition into multiple files where I can group certain methods.

The structure should be something like:

```
master.py   # contains something that puts together all the parts
io.py       # contains function for data input / output
plot.py     # contains functions for plotting / visualization of data
analyze1.py # contains functions to perform certain analysis steps
analyze2.py # contains functions to perform certain analysis steps
```

Comment: "where I can group certain mehtods." What would these groups be?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Provide a rudimentary example for the structure you are facing, explain what those *certain* methods are and give a condition on how you want them sorted.

Comment: @jojo, @ Lutz Horn ... edit made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at mixins:

**plot.py**:

```
class DataPlotter(object):
    def plot(self):
        # lots of code
        my_plot_lib.plot(self.data)  # assume self.data is available in instance
```

**io.py:**

```
class DataIOProvider(object):
    def read(self, filename):
        # lots of code
        self.data = magic_data
```

**master.py:**

```
from plot import DataPlotter
from io import DataIOProvider

class GodDataProcessor(DataPlotter, DataIOProvider):
    def run(self):
        self.read('my_file.txt')
        self.plot()
```

Note that you should wrap your code in some package to avoid name clashing (`io` is a built-in module name in Python).

All base classes may reside in individual modules, and when attribute is set in one of base classes, simply assume it's available in all other classes.